# Why they say commutative field?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, terminology, definition

sometimes I read the term ,,commutative field". But every field is commutative. Why do they say this? For example the english wikipedia page of the Jacobson–Bourbaki theorem.

Edit: Why does my ,,Hey,..." at the beginning of every post disappear?

Comment: In English, the word field implies commutativity, but in French, *corps* is used for both commutative and non-commutative division rings (also known as *skew fields*).

Comment: If I remember correctly, in Emil Artin's *Geometric Algebra*, the term "field" is used to mean "division ring", and what we generally call fields are called "commutative fields."

Comment: Salutations at the beginning of posts  are considered unnecessary in StackExchange, and are automatically deleted.

Comment: Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, the word field implies commutativity, but in French, *corps* is used for both commutative and non-commutative division rings (also known as *skew fields*).

Comment: That's not quite true : in french too it mostly means commutative division ring. I think the distinction is mostly "old-fashioned" vs modern terminology.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Hm, I find that surprising. Every French math book I've ever read writes *corps commutatif* for field, but admittedly they were all written before 1980. And the French equivalent of Wikipedia's [Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) page is [Corps commutatif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corps_commutatif).  But maybe usage is changing over time.

Comment: Yes, I think usage changed overtime - a lot of the books in question were most likely influenced by Bourbaki but I'm french and I've very rarely encountered people saying fields were noncommutative by default (although I did meet one recently, I was surprised)